# How does a switching mixer multiply the two signals?

Tags: theory, electronics, mixer

I understand what a mixer does, and when I see it in a block diagram it's obvious what purpose it serves and how it fits in the overall design of the radio.

However, when I look at the schematics and see how it's created, I don't understand how it works.

For the purposes of this question, I'm referring to only a switching mixer:

[image: Schematic representation of a switching mixer. RF is brought to a switch which can choose the RF directly, or the RF inverted (180 degrees out of phase), where the LO controls the switch.]

How does switching between the RF and the inverted RF at the LO frequency accomplish $RF \cdot LO$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Switching to the inverted signal is equivalent to multiplying by -1. While in an ideal mixer, the RF input can be multiplied by a sinusoidal LO, the switching mixer multiplies by a square LO.

It still works as any mixer would. That is, for each frequency component in the first input $f_1$, and each frequency component in the second input $f_2$, it produces at the output frequency components $f_1 + f_2$ and $f_1 - f_2$.

However, because the LO input must be a square wave (if it's not, the gain of the switching mixer's LO input will make it so), the frequency components of that input are the LO frequency, [plus all its odd harmonics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_wave#Examining_the_square_wave). These must be removed with filtering somewhere up or down the line to avoid undesired mixing products. The advantage is that frequently it's easier to make a good switching mixer with a good filter than it is to make an ideal mixer that produces exactly $RF\cdot LO$ for arbitrary inputs.

Here's a related question on Electrical Engineering.SE: [Can I input a square wave LO into a mixer?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/97322/17608)